# Org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration Class Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, java-8

We are upgrading Springboot from 2.33.RELEASE to 2.7.13 and  while starting server we are getting

**Class Not Found Org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration**

Tried multiple options none of them is working.

Comment: That class doesn't exist in 2.7.13. Remove whatever reference you have to it.

Comment: Not able to find the reference. Any steps to check ?

Comment: Show your dependencies in your post.

Comment: What dependency you are looking for . I can't post whole file as that is in my work laptop

Comment: Post the entire stack trace.

Comment: I found the solution need to update resilenc4j version from 1.4.0 to 1.6.0.  Thanks